# IIS 10.0 SSL Resource not found

Tags: iis

This problem is driving me crazy.

I have set up a few websites in IIS 10.0, enabling only the https protocol. Worecard Certificate installed with no problem.  Accessing web sites from the internet works. Accessing from inside the server doesn't! I get a 404 resource not found error message. Tested http and It works both from outside and inside the Windows server.

Any idea?

Thanks
D.

Comment: When you say "accessing from inside the server", give me some idea of what you are using for a URL.  Is it like `https://machinename/site` or `https://IpAddress/site` or `https://localhost/site` ?   Have you tried each of those ways?

Comment: It Is like https://sitename.com

Comment: Is the problem only with sitename.com or is the problem with all of the ways I listed?

Answer (score 0):

the issue has been solved. It was caused by the AAAA record pointing to a different server IPv6 address. Why Windows prefers IPv6 address for SSL and IPv4 for http remains a mystery to me.

D.